# Adaptive filter without reference signal?

Tags: digital-filter

I am designing FIR Adaptive Filter simulator for CW rejection.

I think that adaptive filter needs 2 inputs.

First, adaptive filter needs desired input.

(it can be received signal)

Second, adaptive filter needs reference input.

(In many books, this input is estimation of noise included in desired input)

However, I can't select reference signal.

(I can't estimate noise(CW))

How can I do?

Comment: Since adaptive filters are closed-loop systems, you will need a reference input. What will be the practical usage of the filter?

Comment: I am trying to implement several digital filter using C++ for only self learning purpose. The reason why I want to implement adaptive filter without reference signal is I already have completed implementation of Fixed FIR Notch filter which can be used for frequency-known CW rejection. I just wanna more powerful digital filter that can be used for frequency-unknown CW rejection

Comment: When you decide the working range of your filter you should be able to decide what will the reference input be.

Comment: Since I am CS major student and this field is not very familiar with me, I don't have any idea what keyword should I search for. can you recommend some topics or keyword for me? My purpose is "Rejection Frequency Unknown CW Jamming from broadband signal". Thank you for your comments. ^^

Comment: I couldn't find any example either. I think your best bet is textbooks. Also you can check MATLAB's help section. There are really good examples there. Maybe you can find about CW filtering.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter in prediction setting (one sample ahead). So you can use the same signal as input and output. The signal for input will be just delayed. The trick is that filter must be set in the way, that it cannot adapt to noise you want to rejects.

It is data reconstruction where the noise is not reconstructed.